# What is difference between living and non-living?

Tags: philosophy, moksha, life, mukti

This question arises from general perspective that one should contemplate and final result is this nothing between God and us. 
Could this be the case with non-living things which seem to concentrate on god more perfectly, and they seem to be super entity whose state humans try to approach. Are they those who have attained their final objective of existence?

**To summarize:**

- Does a human becomes a non living(completely delved in nature) entity at the end of path showed by Hinduism? 
  If it is not so then what makes living different from their counterparts?

and

- What is the state of entity(forgive brevity) which has completed the journey of the path shown by Hinduism?

**My beliefs:**

Please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

- I feel at final(at end of journey to God) there's no emotion no sorrows no joy(which I mean different from bliss - which I believe is a state of stillness i.e. absence of any *disturbance*).

*Please suggest appropriate tags*

Comment: there was a similar question already that was answered. Non-living entities, such as rocks, only contain the Sat of Brahman, and no Chid and no Ananda. The darkness to the human eye at one end of the spectrum is not the same as the darkness at the other end of the spectrum. The stillness of a rock is not the stillness of Brahman.